# How to extract ad sizes from a string with excel regex

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I am trying to extract ad sizes from string. The ad sizes are all set standard sizes. So while I'd prefer to have a regex that looks for a pattern, IE 3 numbers followed by 2 or 3 numbers, hard coding it will also work, since we know what the sizes will be. Here's an example of some of the ad sizes:

300x250

728x90

320x50

I was able to find some VBScript that I modified that almost works, but because my strings that I'm searching are inconsistent, it's pulling too much in some cases. For example:

[image]

You see how it's not matching correctly in every instance.

The VB code I found is actually matching everything EXCEPT that ad sizes. I don't know enough about VBScript to reverse it to just look for ad sizes and pull them. So instead it looks for all other text and removes it.

The code is below. Is there a way to fix the Regex so that it just returns the ad sizes?

```
Function getAdSize(Myrange As Range) As String
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim strOutput As String

    strPattern = "([^300x250|728x90])"

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = Myrange.Value
        strReplace = ""

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
            getAdSize = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
        Else
            getAdSize = "Not matched"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

NOTE, THE DATA IS NOT ALWAYS PRECEDED BY AN UNDERSCORE, SOMETIMES IT IS A DASH OR A SPACE BEFORE AND AFTER.

Comment: In your provided sample data, it looks like the ad size is *always* surrounded by an underscore (`_`).  Is that always the case?  If so this would be pretty easy.

Comment: no not always, sometimes it's a dash or space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Since it's not actually underscore delimited we can't use `Split`.  We can however iterate over the string and extract the "*#x#*" manually.  I have updated the code to reflect this and verified that it works successfully.

```
Public Function ExtractAdSize(ByVal arg_Text As String) As String

    Dim i As Long
    Dim Temp As String
    Dim Ad As String

    If arg_Text Like "*#x#*" Then
        For i = 1 To Len(arg_Text) + 1
            Temp = Mid(arg_Text & " ", i, 1)
            If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                Ad = Ad & Temp
            Else
                If Temp = "x" Then
                    Ad = Ad & Temp
                Else
                    If Ad Like "*#x#*" Then
                        ExtractAdSize = Ad
                        Exit Function
                    Else
                        Ad = vbNullString
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End If

End Function
```

Alternate version of the same function using Select Case boolean logic instead of nested If statements:

```
Public Function ExtractAdSize(ByVal arg_Text As String) As String

    Dim i As Long
    Dim Temp As String
    Dim Ad As String

    If arg_Text Like "*#x#*" Then
        For i = 1 To Len(arg_Text) + 1
            Temp = Mid(arg_Text & " ", i, 1)

            Select Case Abs(IsNumeric(Temp)) + Abs((Temp = "x")) * 2 + Abs((Ad Like "*#x#*")) * 4
                Case 0: Ad = vbNullString       'Temp is not a number, not an "x", and Ad is not valid
                Case 1, 2, 5: Ad = Ad & Temp    'Temp is a number or an "x"
                Case 4, 6: ExtractAdSize = Ad   'Temp is not a number, Ad is valid
                           Exit Function
            End Select
        Next i
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Sorry it isn't. I've updated my question to note that.

Comment: That Select logic is so sexy I wish I could upvote twice.

Comment: Ok I'm going to mark this correct because it's the most all in one solution. How can I modify this to look for /12345/ numbers between two slashes like that? This doesn't use regex right?

Comment: @garek007 That's a fundamentally different question and really should be in a new post.  Would the numbers always be between two `/`s?  If so you, you can use the same split logic I originally showed or you could get it via formula.  I do recommend creating a new question for that though.

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to make about 95% of the required answer - the RegEx below will remove the `DDDxDD` size and would return the rest.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function regExSampler(s As String) As String

    Dim regEx           As Object
    Dim inputMatches    As Object
    Dim regExString     As String

    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With regEx
        .Pattern = "(([0-9]+)x([0-9]+))"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True

        Set inputMatches = .Execute(s)

        If regEx.test(s) Then
            regExSampler = .Replace(s, vbNullString)
        Else
            regExSampler = s
        End If

    End With

End Function

Public Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print regExSampler("uni3uios3_300x250_ASDF.html")
    Debug.Print regExSampler("uni3uios3_34300x25_ASDF.html")
    Debug.Print regExSampler("uni3uios3_8x4_ASDF.html")

End Sub
```

E.g. you would get:

```
uni3uios3__ASDF.html
uni3uios3__ASDF.html
uni3uios3__ASDF.html
```

From here you can continue trying to find a way to reverse the display.

**Edit:**
To go from the 95% to the 100%, [I have asked a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447265/get-the-not-matching-part-of-the-pattern-through-a-regex) and it turns out that the conditional block should be changed to the following:

```
If regEx.test(s) Then
    regExSampler = InputMatches(0)
Else
    regExSampler = s
End If
```

Comment: This would work great if I could make the regex pull exactly the pattern instead of the opposte.

Comment: @garek007 - was trying for about 10 minutes to make it, did not succeed. Will try again tomorrow, but hopefully someone will manage to do it before. If anyone finds a way to do it, feel free to edit the post.

Comment: I will thanks. If I could figure out how to use the regex to just pull the pattern, this would be perfect

Comment: With this, you could change `regExSampler = .Replace(s, vbNullString)` to replace with an unused character, like a tilde. Then, you can just count the characters before and after the tilde and do a `MID`. It's not elegant but oh well.

Comment: If you dim `a` as a byte and change what's inside @Vityata 's `IF` with this, it gets what you want.

`regExSampler = .Replace(s, "~")`

`a = InStr(1, regExSampler, "~", vbTextCompare)`

`regExSampler = Mid(s, a, Len(s) - (Len(regExSampler) - 1))`

Comment: @FernandoJ.Rivera - take a look here, 2 answers of the problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447265/get-the-non-matching-part-of-the-pattern-through-a-regex

Comment: @garek007 - take a look here, 2 answers of the problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447265/get-the-non-matching-part-of-the-pattern-through-a-regex

Answer (score 1):

This formula could work if it's always 3 characters, then x, and it's always between underscores - adjust accordingly.

```
=iferror(mid(A1,search("_???x*_",A1)+1,search("_",A1,search("_???x*_",A1)+1)-(search("_???x*_",A1)+1)),"No match")
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not alwasy the same, that's what makes this so difficult

Comment: can you update your answer and I'll mark it. you need the cred more right?