# How to get numbers between two / in a URL in Excel

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I am trying to extract 4, 5, or 6 numbers in a URL. The number don't always appear in the same place in the URL, sometimes they are in the fourth position, sometimes the fifth, and sometimes, they have a bunch of gobbledygook behind them. Some examples are below.

[image]

I have some VBA that I hacked together from a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427343/how-to-extract-ad-sizes-from-a-string-with-excel-regex/48429300), but as you can see it breaks down on some URLs (image above). How can I modify this, or is there a formula I can use, to always return the highlighted number in the right column?

```
Public Function listNum(Myrange As Range) As String
    Dim regEx           As Object
    Dim inputMatches    As Object
    Dim regExString     As String
    Dim strInput        As String
    Dim a               As Byte

    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With regEx
        .Pattern = "([0-9]{3,7})"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        s = Myrange.Value
        Set inputMatches = .Execute(s)

        If regEx.Test(s) Then
            listNum = .Replace(s, "~")
            a = InStr(1, listNum, "~", vbTextCompare)
            listNum = Mid(s, a, Len(s) - (Len(listNum) - 1))
        Else
            listNum = ""
            'listNum = s 'takes entire contents of cell and puts it in, we do not want that
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

UPDATE: Apparently, they are not always between two slashes, but it looks like they are always 5 characters here are two more URLs. We're back open for business!

```
/listings/?action=display&listingid=31221
/es-gl/listings/?action=display&listingid=30931&menuid=706&hit=1
```

Comment: Is the number always five digits long (no more, no less)?

Comment: I think so, but if possible, I'd like to look for 4 or 6 just in case, but if you have a solution that works with 5 that is ok

Comment: Based on those examples, the regex isn't too hard: https://regexr.com/3jnk1 unfortunately I only really know JavaScript's Regex, so it might need to be adapted to your language.

Comment: Use `.Pattern = "/([0-9]{3,7})/"` and grab `match.SubMatches.Item(0)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not sure how to use the second part, but let me see if that works

Comment: Do you always  expect one single match in each case?

Comment: A simple split on `"/"` together with using `IsNumeric()` and perhaps `Len()` on the returned items should suffice.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes

Comment: @JohnColeman I really don't know VBScript all that well so not sure how to use that

Comment: Your code isn't VBScript in the first place. Most likely it's VBA. Anyway, please clarify what you need to match. Are they always 5 digits? More? Less? What's the range? Can there be other occurrences of such numbers in the same string? Can there be URLs like `/foo/12345/?action=something&listingid=54321` or `/foo/some12345bar/54321/`?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers they are always 5 digits, yes the urls you posted are all possible

Comment: Then which of the numbers do you want to extract? The first? The last? All? Any? Some? Also, why did you accept an answer that can't possibly work for VBA or VBScript?

Comment: I'm using regular expressions with VBA or VBScript or whatever it is.His mostly works. I just need to modify it a little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a formula solution, this should work for you:

```
=--MID(A1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","|"),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)-4)),5)),),0),5)
```

Comment: once again, you are the master

Answer (score 2):

Numbers are at the end of the string and behind `/?`. So:

**Regex**: `(?<=\/)\d+(?=\/\?|\/$)|(?<=listingid=)\d+`

**Details:**

- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times
- `(?<)` and `(?<=)` Positive Lookahead
- `$` asserts position at the end of the string
- `|` or

[RegEx demo](https://regex101.com/r/os06Ab/6)

Comment: That's it! You are so fast, I can't even mark it correct yet. Give me 8 minutes

Comment: Positive lookahead is `(?=...)`, not `(?<...`). `(?<=...)` is a positive lookBEHIND, which neither VBA nor VBScript support.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the numbers, why don't you simply match digits between 2 forward slashes as a capturing group and then extract that group?

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "/(\d{3,7})/"

For Each m In re.Execute(s)
    listNum = m.Submatches(0)
Next
```

Comment: because it's not always in the same spot, also I now have to find listingid= too

Answer (score 0):

Without ***Regex***:

```
Public Function GetNumber(s As String) As String
    Dim a, L As Long
    ary = Split(s, "/")
    For Each a In ary
        L = Len(a)
        If L > 3 And L < 7 And IsNumeric(a) Then
            GetNumber = a
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next a
    GetNumber = ""
End Function
```

[image]

will extract numbers with 4, 5, or 6 digits.