# Get the non-matching part of the pattern through a RegEx

Tags: regex, vba, excel

In this topic, the idea is to take "strip" the numerics, divided by a `x` through a RegEx. -> [How to extract ad sizes from a string with excel regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427343/how-to-extract-ad-sizes-from-a-string-with-excel-regex/48428045?noredirect=1#comment83851284_48428045)

Thus from:

```
uni3uios3_300x250_ASDF.html
```

I want to achieve through RegEx:

```
300x250
```

I have managed to achieve the exact opposite and I am struggling some time to get what needs to be done.
This is what I have until now:

```
Public Function regExSampler(s As String) As String

    Dim regEx           As Object
    Dim inputMatches    As Object
    Dim regExString     As String

    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")    
    With regEx
        .Pattern = "(([0-9]+)x([0-9]+))"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True    
        Set inputMatches = .Execute(s)    
        If regEx.test(s) Then
            regExSampler = .Replace(s, vbNullString)
        Else
            regExSampler = s
        End If    
    End With

End Function

Public Sub TestMe()    
    Debug.Print regExSampler("uni3uios3_300x250_ASDF.html")
    Debug.Print regExSampler("uni3uios3_34300x25_ASDF.html")
    Debug.Print regExSampler("uni3uios3_8x4_ASDF.html")    
End Sub
```

If you run `TestMe`, you would get:

```
uni3uios3__ASDF.html 
uni3uios3__ASDF.html
uni3uios3__ASDF.html
```

And this is exactly what I want to strip through RegEx.

Comment: You don't need capturing groups `()`. `[0-9]+x[0-9]+`

Comment: @S.Kablar - yup, but once I managed to make it working I did not touch it further :)

Comment: The `()` would be nice if he is looking for each of the two dimensions in the future. He may have only posted a portion of the Function for us to see.

Comment: This regex _might_ work: `^(.*\D)(?=\d+x\d+)|(\D+$)`.

Comment: @PedroCorso - if you make it an answer and you care to explain each piece of it, I will select it! Good job, thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the `IF` block to

```
    If regEx.test(s) Then
        regExSampler = InputMatches(0)
    Else
        regExSampler = s
    End If
```

And your results will return

```
300x250
34300x25
8x4
```

This is because `InputMatches` holds the results of the `RegEx` execution, which holds the pattern you were matching against.

Answer (score 4):

As requested by the OP, I'm posting this as an answer:

**Solution**:

```
^.*\D(?=\d+x\d+)|\D+$
```

**Demonstration**: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/0GATkG/2/)

**Explanation**:

- `^.*\D` - Here we're matching every character from the start of the string until it reaches a non-digit (`\D`) character.
- `(?=\d+x\d+)` - This is a positive lookahead. It means that the previous pattern (`^.*\D`) should only match if followed by the pattern described inside it (`\d+x\d+`). The lookahead itself doesn't capture any character, so the pattern `\d+x\d+` isn't captured by the regex.
- `\d+x\d+` - This one should be easy to understand because it's equivalent to `[0-9]+x[0-9]+`. As you see, `\d` is a token that represents any digit character.
- `\D+$` - This pattern matches one or more non-digit characters until it reaches the end of the string.
- Finally, both patterns are linked by an OR condition (`|`) so that the whole regex matches one pattern or another.

Comment: This will fail for strings like [`uni3uios3_300x250_AS4DF.html`](https://regex101.com/r/0GATkG/3)

Comment: I tried to think of a regex that wouldn't assume the existence of underscores on the string, but now that you've pointed out that there could be numbers after the specified pattern, I can only only see this solution: `^.*_(?=\d+x\d+)|_.*$`. Basically, I've adjusted the regex to use `_` as a reference instead of `\D`.